# Why does jdbi bind fail with function as parameter

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc, jdbi

I'm working on an API, written in Java and using an Oracle database which I call via jdbi. I'm writing a helper function to allow me to bind variables for every item in a list.  However, the list is not relevant - the point is my function takes a Query, an object and a callback function (I plan to use Class:getFoo) to get the value from the object.

tl;dr If the value returned is null this fails - but if I bind getFoo directly it works even when null.  Why?

The following works[1]:

```
public class Foo {
    private final String id;

    public Foo(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // Setup DB connection
        PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_IP:MY_PORT:MY_INSTANCE_NAME");
        pds.setUser(MY_USER);
        pds.setPassword(MY_PASSWORD);
        Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create(pds);

        // Create object
        Foo foo = new Foo("bar");
        try {
            // Call DB
            String val = jdbi.withHandle((handle) -> {
                Query query = handle.createQuery("select :foo foo from dual");
                query.bind("foo", foo.getId());                 
                return query.mapTo(String.class).findOnly();
            });
            System.out.println("Value: " + val);            
        } catch( Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> SqlStatement<?> bindDataWith(SqlStatement<?> query, Foo value, String paramName, Function<Foo, ?> paramFn) {
        return query.bind(paramName, paramFn.apply(value));
    }

}
```

It also works if I replace

```
query.bind("foo", foo.getId());
```

with

```
Foo.bindDataWith(query, foo, "foo", Foo::getId);
```

However, if I replace

```
Foo foo = new Foo("bar");
```

with

```
Foo foo = new Foo(null);
```

(in other words, if the getter returns a null String) then the `query.bind("foo", foo.getId());` variant still works but the `Foo.bindDataWith(query, foo, "foo", Foo::getId);` fails!

I don't understand why.  In both cases it should be calling `getId()` on `foo`, which is a string (albeit null).  **Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?**

The complete version which doesn't work is:

```
public class Foo {
    private final String id;

    public Foo(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // Setup DB connection
        PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_IP:MY_PORT:MY_INSTANCE_NAME");
        pds.setUser(MY_USER);
        pds.setPassword(MY_PASSWORD);
        Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create(pds);

        // Create object
        Foo foo = new Foo(null);
        try {
            // Call DB
            String val = jdbi.withHandle((handle) -> {
                Query query = handle.createQuery("select :foo foo from dual");
                Foo.bindDataWith(query, foo, "foo", Foo::getId);
                return query.mapTo(String.class).findOnly();
            });
            System.out.println("Value: " + val);            
        } catch( Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> SqlStatement<?> bindDataWith(SqlStatement<?> query, Foo value, String paramName, Function<Foo, ?> paramFn) {
        return query.bind(paramName, paramFn.apply(value));
    }

}
```

while the console output with the error is

```
Exception while binding named parameter 'foo' [statement:"select :foo foo from dual", rewritten:"select :foo foo from dual", parsed:"ParsedSql{sql='select ? foo from dual', parameters=ParsedParameters{positional=false, parameterNames=[foo]}}", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{foo:NULL}, finder:[]}]
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Exception while binding named parameter 'foo' [statement:"select :foo foo from dual", rewritten:"select :foo foo from dual", parsed:"ParsedSql{sql='select ? foo from dual', parameters=ParsedParameters{positional=false, parameterNames=[foo]}}", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{foo:NULL}, finder:[]}]
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.bindNamed(ArgumentBinder.java:57)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.bind(ArgumentBinder.java:26)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlStatement.internalExecute(SqlStatement.java:1378)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultProducers.lambda$getResultSet$2(ResultProducers.java:59)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.lambda$of$0(ResultIterable.java:53)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.findOnly(ResultIterable.java:97)
    at com.carus.api.bookings.actions.Foo.lambda$0(Foo.java:41)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.withHandle(Jdbi.java:340)
    at com.carus.api.bookings.actions.Foo.main(Foo.java:37)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:3978)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNullCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4472)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNull(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4456)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setNull(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1008)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.StatementProxyFactory.invoke(StatementProxyFactory.java:367)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:194)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.setNull(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.argument.NullArgument.apply(NullArgument.java:39)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.bindNamed(ArgumentBinder.java:54)
    ... 8 more
```

I'm using jdbi 3 and ojdbc8 (12.2.0.1) with java 8.

[1]  I'm putting everything into one class here for simplicity in the example.  In actual fact, my function is a generic that takes a list of values and a map of param name to get function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JDBC (which Jdbi is built on top of), when you bind `null` as a parameter, JDBC needs to be told what data type that `null` is. In your example, we would use the `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR` data type for a `String`.

Jdbi's `SqlStatement.bind()` is overloaded for many different data types, including `String`. When you call one of these strongly-typed overloads, Jdbi knows which JDBC data type to specify if you bind `null`, and takes care of it for you.

Your attempt which uses the `bind("foo", foo.getId())` method directly worked because the compiler recognized `foo.getId()` returns `String`, and calls the right overload for you.

However, your helper function takes a `Function<Foo,?>`, so the compiler interprets that `paramFn.apply()` returns `Object`, not `String`.

The `bind(String, Object)` variant can't guess what data type you have if you pass in null. Database vendors often will accept some data type as a kind of wildcard for nulls--however they vary in *which* data type they allow.

- Postgres accepts `Types.OTHER` (which Jdbi uses by default) for untyped nulls.
- H2 accepts `Types.NULL` (which isn't actually a type constant).
- Some experimentation revealed that Oracle JDBC accepts `Types.NULL` as well

Jdbi provides a configuration setting so you can tell it what to use with untyped nulls. The following code should fix your problem:

```
Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create(...);
jdbi.getConfig(Arguments.class)
    .setUntypedNullArgument(new NullArgument(Types.NULL));
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had assumed it would resolve the type of the callback first, but that works now.

Comment: What do you mean with _"`Types.NULL` (which isn't actually a type constant)"_?

Comment: Per the javadoc, `Types.NULL` is a constant for the SQL _value_ `NULL`. There is no null _type_. JDBC muddied the waters by putting that constant in the `Types` class.